# Como posso testar uma exception no meu código com unittest?

Tags: python, exceção, testes

estou estudando um pouco do unittest do Python e empaquei nessa questão.
No meu código o usuário deve digitar um valor valido, se ocorrer um valor invalido deve cair na exception, porem como posso testa isso ?
Meu código esta o seguinte:

```
if moeda not in (2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100):
   raise Exception('Valor de moeda invalido.')
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar [TestCase.assertRaises](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises):

```
import unittest

class SeusTestes(unittest.TestCase):
    def testa_excecao(self):
        self.assertRaises(SuaException, objeto.suaFuncao)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```